# SSHD reverse mapping fails, but nslookup, dig, and host resolve correctly

Tags: dns, ssh, dhcp, bind

I just set up a dhcp/dns server to manage my home network. After I got everything up and running (and maybe before - I wasn't paying close attention), I noticed that logging into ssh was slow. I started sshd in debug mode with `/sbin/sshd -ddd` and fired up a second PuTTy instance.

Of course, the culprit was immediately obvious:

```
debug3: Trying to reverse map address 10.0.0.22.
reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for mt.local [10.0.0.22] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
```

It couldn't reverse map my IP to my hostname. Which is peculiar, considering that the DNS records are all in order according to nslookup:

```
[root@media] # nslookup mt.local
Server:        10.0.0.2
Address:       10.0.0.2#53

Name:   mt.local
Address: 10.0.0.22

[root@media] # nslookup 10.0.0.22
Server:        10.0.0.2
Address:       10.0.0.2#53

22.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa  name = mt.local
```

host:

```
[root@media] # host mt.local
mt.local has address 10.0.0.22
[root@media] # host 10.0.0.22
22.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer mt.local.
```

and dig:

```
[root@media] # dig mt.local

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-P2-RedHat-9.9.4-12.P2.fc20 <<>> mt.local
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 12144
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mt.local.                      IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mt.local.               300     IN      A       10.0.0.22

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
local.                  300     IN      NS      media.local.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
media.local.            300     IN      A       10.0.0.2

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.0.2#53(10.0.0.2)
;; WHEN: Tue Jul 15 23:02:34 EDT 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 89

[root@media] # dig -x 10.0.0.22

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-P2-RedHat-9.9.4-12.P2.fc20 <<>> -x 10.0.0.22
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 5476
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;22.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa.                IN      PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
22.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa. 300     IN      PTR     mt.local.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
0.0.10.in-addr.arpa.    300     IN      NS      media.local.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
media.local.            300     IN      A       10.0.0.2

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.0.2#53(10.0.0.2)
;; WHEN: Tue Jul 15 23:03:59 EDT 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 109
```

And, for the sake of verbosity, my `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
search local
nameserver 10.0.0.2
```

I can't find any reason that reverse mapping should fail. And I can't find any reason for it to hang so long before it does fail - the DNS server is only 0.5 ms away.

Yeah, I know I could just turn reverse mapping off, but that's not really the point. I appreciate any and all assistance!

I should probably note that this is on a 10.0.0.0/24 network; modem/gateway is at 10.0.0.1; dns/dhcp/the box I'm talking about (media) is at 10.0.0.2; and my desktop (mt) is at 10.0.0.22. Local domain is .local, and I have reverse DNS mapping tied to DHCP.

Comment: `dig`, `host` and `nslookup` all check DNS, but nothing else and typically systems are configured to use the `/etc/hosts` file first and may be configured in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to use other host databases (e.g. NIS, LDAP) in precedence to DNS as well. The check `getent hosts 10.0.0.22` honors nsswitch.conf and matches what the system resolver and `getaddrinfo ` will return.

Comment: do you show resolv.conf of ssh client or ssh server machine?

Comment: @HBruijn Unfortunately, getent gives the same results: getent hosts 10.0.0.22 returns 10.0.0.22  mt.local.

Comment: @Bushmills That's the resolv.conf for the server. Client is cygwin/windows.

Comment: I'd partition problem domain, by running tcpdump or tshark, monitoring udp/53 dest traffic, to verify that actually your nameserver is queries when attempting to reverse resolve. Maybe you're logging those queries on nameserver so you could check logs instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be both simple and stupid, and was caused by operator error. Apparently, in my infinite wisdom, I had the following configuration (in my dhcpd.conf) for the static lease for mt:

```
host mightyturing {
     hardware ethernet <MAC>;
     option host-name "mightyturing";
     ddns-hostname "mt";
     fixed-address 10.0.0.22;
};
```

So SSHD was right - the reverse map doesn't match the set hostname. Changing the `ddns-hostname` to "mightyturing" fixed it. Changing `option host-name` to `mt` probably would have worked as well.

At least, I *think* that was the problem... it stopped hanging after fixing the dhcp config and renewing my IP.

Regardless, thank you all for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

.local is often considered a 'special' domain. avahi/bonjour/mdns etc use it as the domain name, and while you don't say what you are using to serve DNS, I guess it's not avahi.

What does the 'hosts' line in /etc/nsswitch.conf look like?

nslookup, host, and dig will be using your configured resolvers, however ssh will be using nsswitch.conf, which will give it a list of options to step through. One of those options may be mdns or mdns4, eg:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4 mdns
```

I suggest either changing your local domain name to something other than .local, or removing any mdns* entries from the hosts: line in nsswitch.conf, eg:

```
hosts:          files dns
```

Comment: No, not avahi. I like to make things difficult; I'm using Bind9. The line in nsswitch.conf was `hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns` as you predicted, but changing it to `hosts: files dns` didn't make any difference.